# How to create a custom Jenkins "New item" type

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've just started working with Jenkins plugin development and have some questions: 
How to create a custom Jenkins "New item" type which should have some predefined build parameters ? 
Could you please provide a tutorial or an example how to do such things.

I am thinking of the following solutions: 
- develop a custom job type which will have build parameters predefined inside it 
- develop a parametrized job custom build parameter type which will get more than one value during the build setep

I have tried to create parametrized job custom build type for my plugin but in my case I need to define more than one build parameter which as I see is not possible because Jenkins's buildWithParameters function gets only one value from my type regarding of this: 
https://gitorious.org/jenkinsci/jenkins/source/bbdf5c21153c7e9d60d6ed158d32aa8852f00501:core/src/main/java/hudson/model/ParametersDefinitionProperty.java

Thanks,
Mane H

Comment: could you please refer github code of existing plugin such as sectored view plugin.. it ll give you an better idea

Comment: I have added a simple project, please find the link below:
https://github.com/hambardzumyan-mane/new_job_type.git

I want to achieve either of the following:
- make name, surname and middle name parametrized build arguments
- have “This build is parameterized” automatically checked in my “New Style Project”  and 3 build arguments (name, surname and middle name) automatically added